# JavaScript: Sort an array of objects by a numeric property in each object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a hard time understanding how to use the array.sort() method to sort an array of objects based on a numeric value found in every object. Essentially I have a scenario of the following form:

```
var myarray = []
myarray.push({name: "alex", age: 8})
myarray.push({name: "ben", age: 57})
myarray.push({name: "dan", age: 32})
```

The initial order of the result would be "alex, ben, dan". Now I want to sort this array by age, so the oldest people are first on the list. After sorting the order should be "ben, dan, alex". How do I achieve this in the simplest way possible?

Answer (score 36):

You can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and the [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method like so:

```js
var myarray = []
myarray.push({name: "alex", age: 8})
myarray.push({name: "ben", age: 57})
myarray.push({name: "dan", age: 32});

var res = myarray.sort(({age:a}, {age:b}) => b-a);
console.log(res);
```

Or, if you don't feel comfortable with destructing, you can use regular [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) to access the `age` property:

```js
var myarray = []
myarray.push({name: "alex", age: 8})
myarray.push({name: "ben", age: 57})
myarray.push({name: "dan", age: 32});

var res = myarray.sort((a, b) => b.age-a.age);
console.log(res);
```

The way `.sort` works is defined by what you return from the callback function you pass in. If you return:

- `<= -1` then `a` will come before `b`.
- `0` then keep `a` and `b` in the same positions
- `>= 1` then `b` will come before `a`

Thus, by calculating the difference between the two ages, this "naturally" gives the correct values to properly sort your array.

Comment: This has the incorrect output - it should be `ben`, `dan`, `alex` as shown in the question.

Comment: I think destructing adds an unnecessary level of complexity for newbies. age => age.b - age.a makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: @AdrianBrand yeah, I can see that. I've added an alternative

Comment: **Additional note:** The `.sort()` method does two things, it changes the original array so that it is in sorted order, and it also returns a reference to your original array (which is now sorted). In the above examples `myarray` also becomes sorted. If you don't want `myarray` sorted, you can make a shallow copy of it before you sort: `myarray.slice().sort(...)`

Comment: Oh, I see what I did wrong. In .Net I can just do `mylist.Sort(a => a.Age)` to sort on one property using the property type's default comparer. Seems that doesn't work here.

Answer (score 21):

**ES6**

```
myarray.sort((a,b) => b.age - a.age)
```

**ES5**

```
myarray.sort(function(a,b){return b.age - a.age})
```

Detailed description of the sort function can be found here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

*Edited to sort in descending order as OP asked

Answer (score 9):

Thanks everyone. I solved it by using this option:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.score - a.score })
```

Comment: This goes descening order.  like 9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1 for ascending we can use. `a.score - b.score`

Comment: Adds some overhead but you can simply `reverse` a descending result:

`data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.score - a.score }).reverse()`

Comment: Using `reverse()` unnecessarily increases complexity, simply switch `a` and `b` in the subtraction.

Answer (score 5):

```
myarray.sort((a,b) => b.age - a.age)
```

Is the correct answer but nobody has helped with OP's question of having a hard time understanding sort. The function you pass into sort is the comparison function that when comparing two elements of the array should return less than 0 for a comes first, 0 if they are equal and greater than 0 for b comes first.

I use this default comparer function in my projects

```
defaultCompare = (a, b) => (!a && !b ? 0 : !a ? -1 : !b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0);
```

as undefined, null, NaN and other falsey values can throw a spanner in there on you.

Comment: Perhaps use nullish coalesce 

`defaultCompare = (a, b) => (a??0 - b??0);`

Comment: Or logical OR: `defaultCompare = (a, b) => (a||0 - b||0);`

Comment: @vogomatix that is my sort function I use for numbers but the above defaultCompare plays well with strings and dates as well as numbers.