# how to filtered higher score in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
const students = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Sherlock",
      score:90
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Genta",
      score: 75
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Ai",
      score: 80
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      name: "Budi",
      score:85
    }
  ]
```

and result

```
{ id: '1', name: 'Sherlock', score: 90 },
{ id: '4', name: 'Budi', score: 85 }
```

Comment: This might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value

Comment: [Sort by `score`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54623130/1220550), then take the first 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to filter the students by their score first, and then sort them by their score (and name if scores are the same).

```js
const filterStudentsByMinScore = (students, minScore) =>
  students
    .filter(({ score }) => score >= minScore)
    .sort(({ name: na, score: sa }, { name: nb, score: sb }) =>
      sb - sa || na.localeCompare(nb));

const students = [
  { id: "1", name: "Sherlock" , score: 90 },
  { id: "2", name: "Genta"    , score: 75 },
  { id: "3", name: "Ai"       , score: 80 },
  { id: "4", name: "Budi"     , score: 85 },
];

const results = filterStudentsByMinScore(students, 85);

console.log(results);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```