# Sorting with Number and Strings in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have array like this :

```
array =[{limit:50}, {limit:40}, {limit:10},{limit:'unlimited'}]
```

How to sort this array so that, when ascending unlimited comes at the last index and when descending unlimited comes at the top index.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and their linked pages. We need to see your attempt to solve the problem. Without that, it looks like you didn't try and are asking us for references to off-site tutorials or to write code for you, which are both off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest may be to use the "standard" [numerical sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54623130/javascript-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-a-numeric-property-in-each-object) for ascending, and when you need descending, then just apply `.reverse()` to it as an extra action:

```js
let array =[{limit:50}, {limit:40}, {limit:10},{limit:'unlimited'}];

array.sort((a,b) => a.limit - b.limit);

console.log(array);

array.reverse();

console.log(array);
```

Comment: if you want the reverse order, you can do it directly from the sort function.
`array.sort((a,b) => b.limit - a.limit);`
Reversing the array is an additional O(N) pass that can be avoided

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and the most straightforward way is to use the Array built in functions of `sort` and `reverse`

In case you require ascending:

```
let array =[{limit:50}, {limit:40}, {limit:10},{limit:'unlimited'}]
array.sort((a,b) => a.limit - b.limit);
```

In case you require descending:

```
let array =[{limit:50}, {limit:40}, {limit:10},{limit:'unlimited'}]
array.sort((a,b) => a.limit - b.limit);
array.reverse();
```

Comment: How it is different from the above answer ?